# How can I print a Word document in C# without showing the print dialog

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word

I'm using C# and Word Interop to automate a mail merge.  I want to print each merged document to the default printer with the default options but don't want the print options dialog to show each time.  How can I do this?  When I try this code on my client machine, a print options dialog displays when the PrintOut method is called.  Here's my code:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = false;
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();
object oTemplatePath = Path.Combine(baseDir, fileName);
oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add((ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
object copies = "1";
object pages = "";
object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
object items = Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
object pageType = Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
object oTrue = true;
object oFalse = false;
oWordDoc.PrintOut(ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting [oWord.ActivePrinter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821995.aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd: I have not tried that, but this is something that needs to work on multiple client computers, and I have no way of knowing their printer names.  The idea is for my functionality to use the default printer with all default options.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one, it works ok for word docs.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Verb = "print";
        p.FileName = file;

        p.Start();
```